# mongodb group by where field not equals to max

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get all documents that (grouped by 2 fields) are not equal to their max.

There are multiple versions for every document, so the query to view all the latest versions is:

```
db.getCollection('datatype').aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {
               "name": "$name",
               "applicationId": "$applicationId"
               },
           latest: { $max: "$version" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Now I need the complement of this query (all previous versions, not the latest).

I tried some queries, like the below, but none worked.

```
db.getCollection('datatype').aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {
               "name": "$name",
               "applicationId": "$applicationId"
               },
           previousVersions: 
               { $ne: {$max: "$version"} }
               
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

EDIT:
input/output examples:
input:

```
db.getCollection('datatype').insertMany([
   { applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(1) },
   { applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(2) },
   { applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(3) },
   { applicationId: "BBBB", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(1) },
   { applicationId: "CCCC", name: "bar", version: NumberInt(1) },
   { applicationId: "CCCC", name: "bar", version: NumberInt(2) }
])
```

So the expected results from the first query that takes the latest version from applicationId+name, is:

```
{ applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(3) },
{ applicationId: "BBBB", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(1) },
{ applicationId: "CCCC", name: "bar", version: NumberInt(2) }
```

And my desired output is basically the complement of this query, that takes all the results besides the latest version (all these documents has an updated version, for their corresponding applicationId+name)

```
{ applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(1) },
{ applicationId: "AAAA", name: "foo", version: NumberInt(2) },
{ applicationId: "CCCC", name: "bar", version: NumberInt(1) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$sort` order by `version` in descending order
- `$group` by `name` and `applicationId` and construct the all versions array
- `$slice` to remove latest version from versions array
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `previousVersions` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { version: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "name": "$name",
        "applicationId": "$applicationId"
      },
      previousVersions: { $push: "$version" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      applicationId: "$_id.applicationId",
      name: "$_id.name",
      previousVersions: {
        $slice: ["$previousVersions", 1, { $size: "$previousVersions" }]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$previousVersions" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RAIR7sTCPyG)

---

If you are looking for original document of previous version you can try,

- `$sort` order by `version` in descending order
- `$group` by `name` and `applicationId` and construct the all grouped documents
- `$slice` to remove latest version from versions array
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `previousVersions` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `previousVersions` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { version: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "name": "$name",
        "applicationId": "$applicationId"
      },
      previousVersions: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      previousVersions: {
        $slice: ["$previousVersions", 1, { $size: "$previousVersions" }]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$previousVersions" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$previousVersions" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2oznpx8Nu0A)

Comment: great thanks. Can u just add the _id of the corresponding documents? My end goal is to move them to a different collection.

Comment: i have added project stage to format result, how you will move this documents to different collection? if you use `$out` it will add by default `_id`.

Comment: see i have added second option as well if you are looking for exact previous version document with its original _id.

Comment: Yeah I can use `$out`, but what bothers me is deleting from current collection. I think I'll just write a python script to remove these by ID.

Comment: it depends, i am not sure its one time transaction or you implementing any process in your current project. i think yes you can delete by _id.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command to do this, if the natural order of the documents in the `db` matches the `version` order and you're not using any specific indexes on other fields who might mix the order up you could use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to remove the unwanted version, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "name": "$name",
        "applicationId": "$applicationId"
      },
      not_latest: {
        "$push": "$version"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      not_latest: {
        $slice: [
          "$not_latest",
          0,
          {
            $subtract: [
              {
                $size: "$not_latest"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0R2leacnFiM)

If for some reason you can't rely on the order just add a `$sort` stage with `version: 1` prior to the `$group` stage and use the same code.

And if for some reason you don't want to `$sort` you could temporarily save the `latest` and use it to filter out the final results, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "name": "$name",
        "applicationId": "$applicationId"
      },
      not_latest: {
        "$push": "$version"
      },
      latest: {
        $max: "$version"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      not_latest: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$not_latest",
          as: "elem",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$elem",
              "$latest"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kUctjWPyv-X)